# Flask : BuildError

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/sign/<error>')
def sign(error=''):
    return render_template('sign.html',er=error)
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST','GET'])
def process():
    ch = request.form['box']
    if ch == 'ok':
        name = request.form['name']
        comment = request.form['comment']

        signature = Comments(name=name, comment=comment)
        db.session.add(signature)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else :
        er='please check'
        return redirect(url_for('sign',error=er))
```

sign.html have this line of code

```
<div style="color: red;">{{er}}</div>
```

this is a picture for what i get
[BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'sign'. Did you forget to specify values ['error']?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8P22.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom of your traceback is cut off, but it looks like in your index.html template you're calling `url_for` for your `sign` route without specifying a value for `error`.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred because /sign/error, error is none. 
Either you can try changing `def sign(error='')` to `def sign(error)`, or change `er='please check'` to 'pleasecheck'(that doesn't contain blank)